# CSS last three children only if condition

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to learn how to select the `<li>` among the last three elements of a `<ul>` such that their (one-based) index is greater than the greatest multiple of 3 which is smaller than the number of list elements.

So for example:

- if there are 9 `<li>` elements in `<ul>`, I want elements 1-6 to have font-weight:normal and elements 7,8 and 9 to have font-weight:bold.
- if there are 8 `<li>` elements in `<ul>`, I want elements 1-6 to have font-weight:normal and elements 7 and 8 to have font-weight:bold.
- if there are 7 `<li>` elements in `<ul>`, I want elements 1-6 to have font-weight:normal and element 7 to have font-weight:bold.

I tried this CSS selector but it seems to make everything bold:

```css
li:nth-last-child(1n+0),
li:nth-last-child(2n+0),
li:nth-last-child(3n+0) {font-weight:bold;}
```

How else do I do this?

Comment: if there are 10 items, would you expect the first 1-7 items have normal font-weight, or would the last 4 items be bold?

Comment: @haxxxton if there are 10 items, then i want the first nine to be normal font weight and the tenth item to be bold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want

```css
li:nth-last-child(-n+3):nth-child(3n+1),
li:nth-last-child(-n+3):nth-child(3n+1) ~ * {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

That is, it selects the element among the last 3 whose index mod 3 is 1. And then it also adds the following siblings (if any).

```js
/* Tests */
document.styleSheets[0].ownerNode.textContent += ".fail { color: red; } .fail::after { content: ' - FAIL'; }"
for (var i=0; i<10; ++i) {
  var ul = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
  for (var j=0; j<=i; ++j) {
    var li = ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(j+1+'-th item '));
  }
  for (var j=0; j<=i; ++j) {
    var li = ul.children[j];
    var isSelected = getComputedStyle(li).fontWeight === '700';
    if(isSelected !== (j >= Math.floor(i/3)*3)) li.className = "fail";
  }
}
```

```css
li:nth-last-child(-n+3):nth-child(3n+1),
li:nth-last-child(-n+3):nth-child(3n+1) ~ * {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

In case there are more than three elements, you can simplify it to

```css
li:nth-last-child(-n+4):nth-child(3n) ~ * {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

That is, it gets the element(s) among the last 4 whose index is a multiple of 3. And then it selects the following siblings.

```js
/* Tests */
document.styleSheets[0].ownerNode.textContent += ".fail { color: red; } .fail::after { content: ' - FAIL'; }"
for (var i=0; i<10; ++i) {
  var ul = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
  for (var j=0; j<=i; ++j) {
    var li = ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(j+1+'-th item '));
  }
  for (var j=0; j<=i; ++j) {
    var li = ul.children[j];
    var isSelected = getComputedStyle(li).fontWeight === '700';
    if(isSelected !== (j >= Math.floor(i/3)*3)) li.className = "fail";
  }
}
```

```css
li:nth-last-child(-n+4):nth-child(3n) ~ * {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

And if you dislike universal selectors,

```css
li:nth-last-child(-n+3):nth-child(3n+1),
li:nth-last-child(-n+2):nth-child(3n+2),
li:nth-last-child(-n+1):nth-child(3n+3)
```

```js
/* Tests */
document.styleSheets[0].ownerNode.textContent += ".fail { color: red; } .fail::after { content: ' - FAIL'; }"
for (var i=0; i<10; ++i) {
  var ul = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
  for (var j=0; j<=i; ++j) {
    var li = ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(j+1+'-th item '));
  }
  for (var j=0; j<=i; ++j) {
    var li = ul.children[j];
    var isSelected = getComputedStyle(li).fontWeight === '700';
    if(isSelected !== (j >= Math.floor(i/3)*3)) li.className = "fail";
  }
}
```

```css
li:nth-last-child(-n+3):nth-child(3n+1),
li:nth-last-child(-n+2):nth-child(3n+2),
li:nth-last-child(-n+1):nth-child(3n+3) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: both options seem to fail if there are more than 9 items. https://jsfiddle.net/bxaaj5r0/6/

Comment: @haxxxton That behavior is expected.

Comment: Yep, OP just clarified in the comments, apologies, my confusion over the question title

Comment: "And if you dislike universal selectors," just replace the * with a type selector...?

Comment: @BoltClock Well, I didn't explain that very well, I meant type selectors still match lots of things, and `*` is needed in the more general case the elements may have different types (but here `li` would be enough).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `n` notation on `:nth-last-child` you can just use a number on `:nth-child`. Mind you, both of these solutions are technically *targeting the first 6 items* to override the styles that would be applied to the remaining list items.

```
li{
    font-weight:bold;
}
li:nth-child(1),
li:nth-child(2),
li:nth-child(3),
li:nth-child(4),
li:nth-child(5),
li:nth-child(6){
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bxaaj5r0/4/)**

---

Alternatively, if you wanted to use `n` notation you could use

```
li{
    font-weight:bold;
}
li:nth-child(-n+6){
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

to select the first 6 elements

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bxaaj5r0/5/)**

---

If you truly wanted to select all elements after the last 6 you would use:

```
li:nth-child(n+6) ~ *{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bxaaj5r0/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `li:nth-last-child(-n+3)`

That should give you the last 3 elements even if the list is dynamic. Whether the list has 10, 20 or 30 elements, it will always target the last 3